# javascript dom conflict: how to start at column 2

Tags: javascript, object, dom

My JavaScript DOM model is conflicting. I have an exporttable who on one side generate an indexnumber and on the other side imports data (firsName, lastName and points from an importform. I try to get the indexnumber on column 1, firstName in 2, lastName in 3 and points in 4.

At this moment indexnumber is in column 1(good) but firstName starts in column 1 too (not good). If adding (see script) newRow.insertCell(1); the console protests.

Who can help me?

```
<script>
    var button3 = document.getElementById("button2");
        button3.onclick= addData;

        function addData() {
            // collect data firstname, lastname, points

            var firstName = document.getElementById("firstname");
            var lastName = document.getElementById("lastname");
            var Points = document.getElementById("points");

            var exportTable = document.getElementById("exportTable");
            var newRow = exportTable.insertRow(-1);
            var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0); //I can not start here with insertCell(0); 
            var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
            var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);

            cel1.innerHTML = firstName.value;
            cel2.innerHTML = lastName.value;
            cel3.innerHTML = Points.value;


            //instal number
            var amountRows = exportTable.rows.length;

            for (var i = 1; i < amountRows; i++) {
                exportTable.rows[i].children[0].innerHTML = i;
            }
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Should work -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/uskmf9z1/

Comment: you cannot skip inserting at position 0 and go straight to 1, because 1 would then be the first cell.. it doesn't make sense to do that.

Comment: this I understand. But how to solve this problem? How to get the indexnumber in column 1 and firstName in column 2 ?